# Can anyone help me get my method to not print out the number count after it prints out the number of alarms the user inputs?

Tags: java, methods

The challenge for my classwork was to write code that prints out the number of Alarms equal to the user's input. I print out the number of alarms but it also adds the original user input when I run it. Is there anyway I can remove the number it prints(int count) from the return?

```
import java.util.*;
public class classw2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("How many times would you like it to print?");
    int count = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(alarm(count));

}
public static int alarm (int count)
{
    if (count < 1)
        System.out.println("Use another number");



        for(int counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm!");
        }//for loop
    return count;
}//new method
}
```

Comment: Replace `System.out.println(alarm(count))` with just `alarm(count)` ?

Comment: You can invoke your method as `void` instead of printing its return value, i.e. instead of `System.out.println(alarm(count));`, just `alarm(count);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

```
import java.util.*;
public class classw2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("How many times would you like it to print?");
int count = scan.nextInt();
alarm(count);

}
public static void alarm (int count)
{
    if (count < 1)
        System.out.println("Use another number");

        for(int counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("Alarm!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem your sourcecode has, is that you print the returnValue of your `alarm(int count)` function (which in your case is int).

In order to fix this you need to fix to things:

1. Change the return value of your method to `void`
2. Don't call your method as a parameter to println, you are already calling the println function inside your method.

In addition you should read up on these topics (parameters, return values, etc.) as they are truely essential ;)